# Core Data: How to do a second fetch limited to the results of an earlier fetch?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

This seems like it may be a trivial question, but I am new to Core Data and to databases.

In my application, I perform a fetch and display the results.  Then, based on user input, I need to cull those results down.  That is, I need to do a new search on only the results of the first fetch, but based on an entirely different parameter.  (Sometimes, the second fetch will be based on an attribute, other times on a to-many relationship.)  What is the optimal way to do this?

I have figured out two options to do this, but neither seems very good:

1. In the first fetch, prefetch all the data needed for the second fetch.  Then, don't do a second fetch, but just iterate through the array of results of the first fetch, looking for matches to the new conditions of the second fetch.  *This method has the disadvantage that I have to trudge thru the array and don't take advantage of performance benefits of Core Data.*
2. For the second fetch, disregard the first and do a brand new fetch with a compound predicate composed of the conditions for the first fetch and those for the second.  *This has the disadvantage that Core Data must look thru the entire database again to do the same search it already did.*

Is there a way, in a second fetch, to tell Core Data to search only thru the entity objects returned in an earlier fetch?

Comment: Was the first fetch fast enough? If so then the second fetch with a compound predicate will almost certainly be fine. Seems like this could be premature optimization.

Comment: @Adam Eberbach:  Actually, right now I'm redesigning the database to optimize for the types of fetches I need to do.  So, I don't know.  But, I was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this that I'm missing.  It seems like a very common thing to do, to have to do a second search on the set of results of an earlier search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it figured out.

For the first option, it's pretty easy.  You have your array of objects, and you can just do `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` or `-[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]` to reduce the array according to your needs.  You don't need to actually iterate through the array yourself; just use a predicate like you would with a fetch request.

For the second option, that's also pretty easy.  You take the predicate from your first request and `AND` it with your new predicate:

```
NSPredicate *original = ...;
NSPredicate *newCondition = ...;
NSPredicate *newFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:original, newCondition, nil]];
```

Personally, I usually find the first option to be simpler overall.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the methods to filter an array with a predicate:  very nice.  But, filtering an array is not as efficient as doing the same work directly in the database.  The question is:  is it possible to do the second fetch in the database, somehow telling Core Data to look only at the results of the first fetch?  That is, without having to do the first fetch all over again using a compound predicate?

Comment: Or, is it possible to somehow save the results of the first fetch in Core Data?  And then run the second fetch on only those results and not the full database?

Comment: @salo.dm you say "filtering an array is not as efficient as doing the same work directly in the database", but have you proven that?  Have you tried filtering the array yourself and found the performance to be worse than executing the query yourself?  As for "saving the results", Core Data does not (AFAIK) have a way to do that.

Comment: No, I haven't done any testing yet.  Just trying to come up with a good design for now, and then tweak.  When I say that the database is more efficient, I'm just going on the WWDC videos on optimizing Core Data and the Stanford course that's on iTunes.  They both recommend to do as much filtering as possible in Core Data because SQL is particularly efficient at it.  ...But, I'm getting the feeling that databases just don't do sequential fetches the way I described.  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @salo.dm I've never seen anything in the SQLite API that would suggest it can do "sequential fetches" like you've described (C bindings: http://sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).  And if SQLite doesn't support it, anything Core Data did would have to be emulated in code (by doing two requests or compounding the predicates like I showed)

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much clears it up for me, and your recommendations are very helpful.

Comment: @Dave deLong: btw, awesome answer! very complete